# Error multiplying permutations in cycle notation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can someone tell me where this calculation goes wrong?
I get (2 3 4)(1 2 3 4 5 6)^-1 = (1 6 5 2).
My book and Mathematica get (1 6 5 4).
I have read several explanations of how to multiply permutations in cycle notation and have
worked dozens of examples successfully, but I always get this one wrong.

(2 3 4)(1 2 3 4 5 6)^-1 = (2 3 4)(6 5 4 3 2 1) = (2 3 4)(1 6 5 4 3 2)

1 -> 6 then 6 is unchanged  giving  (1 6

6 -> 5 then 5 in unchanged  giving  (1 6 5

5 -> 4 then 4 -> 2          giving  (1 6 5 2

2 -> 1 then 1 is unchanged  completing the cycle  giving (1 6 5 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are multiplying permutations right-to-left, but your book (and Mathematica) are multiplying permutations left-to-right. Both conventions (left-to-right and right-to-left) are in common use, so it's important to know which one a particular author is using when reading.

Comment: Thanks, I see that you both are correct. I double checked in the book that this example appeared in (Abstract Algebra and Solution by Radical by Maxfield and Maxfield) and when they explained how to multiply cycles on p53, they went from right to left. So they aren't even following their own procedure later in the book.

Answer (score 1):

You are multiplying from right to left. Your book and Mathematica are multiplying left to right.